# How can I avoid heap out of memory?

Tags: javascript, heap-memory

I wrote this code to get ended my homework as a practice.

This code controls browser with nightmare.js.It just iterates clicking button and waiting for a sec.

But this code issued an error of heap out of memory. I just tried out "--max-old-space-size=4096". but it didn't work...
ANYONE HELP ME??

I checked other than iterations can work. Then putting iterations..., it cannot work due to heap out of memory.
To be honest, I am not good at coding and English. If there are any miswriting, ask me please!

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({show: true});


const LinguaURL = "";
const NumberOfMine = "";
const PwdOfMine = "";

var i,j = -1;
var selection, progress;
var radioSelect = -1;

function main() {
  nightmare
    .goto(LinguaURL)
    .wait(1000)
    .type("input[type='text']", NumberOfMine)
    .type("input[type='password']", PwdOfMine)
    .click("input[type='submit']")
    .wait(5000)
    .click('a[href="javascript:document.Study.submit()"]')
    .wait(3000)
    .click("input[type='button']")
    .wait(3000);

    for(i = 3;i<43;i++){
      nightmare
        .click('a[onclick="unit_view_page(\''+i.toString()+'\');"]');
        while(true){
          j++;

          if(j % 4 == 0){
          nightmare
            .click('input[onclick="select_unit(\'drill\', \''+(1833+j).toString()+'\', \'\');"]')
            .wait(1000);

          while(true){
            radioSelect++;

            nightmare
              .click('input[id="answer_0_' + radioSelect.toString() +'"]')
              .wait(1000)
              .click('input[id="ans_submit"]')
              .wait(1000)
              .evaluate(function (){
                 return selection = document.querySelector('.btn btn-answer-view form-font-size');
              })
              .evaluate(function (){
                return progress = document.querySelector('btn btn-next-problem form-font-size');
              });

              if(selection == null && progress == null)break;

              if(selection != null){
                continue;
              }else{
                nightmare
                  .click('input[class="btn btn-next-problem form-font-size"]');
                continue;
              }
          }
          if((j + 1) % 10 == 0)break;
          }
        }
      }
      nightmare
        .wait(100)
        .end()
        .then(console.log);
}

main();
```

Comment: You should describe what your code does in your question.

Comment: Okay!, I’m sorry.

Comment: Ensure your code isn't getting stuck in the `while(true)` loops. These potential infinite loop can cause you to run out of heap.

Comment: I see... so... Can loops other than while(true) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, I think this is the reason.

```
function main() {
    for(i = 3;i<43;i++){
        while(true){
            j++;
            if(j % 4 == 0){
                while(true){
                    /**** break for the second while. ****/
                    if(selection == null && progress == null) break;
                    if(selection != null){
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                /**** break for the first while. ****/
                // But this code will be run if 'j % 4 == 0',
                // and I can't see any assigned the value to 'j' variable inside of 'if'. 
                // There's no way the result will be true.
                if((j + 1) % 10 == 0) { break; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
var j = -1;
var limit = 2000 * 4;
while(true){
    j++;
    if(j != 0 && j % 1000 == 0) console.log("loop: " + j);
    // here we go.
    if(j % 4 == 0){
        while(true){
            break;
        }
        // But this code will be run if 'j % 4 == 0',
        // and I can't see any assigned the value to 'j' variable inside of 'if'. 
        // There's no way the result will be true.
        if((j + 1) % 10 == 0) { console.log("your if statement"); break; }
        // limit
        if (j == limit) { console.log("break using limit"); break; }
    }
    // Maybe (do you just want to run ten times?)
    // if((j + 1) % 10 == 0) { console.log("[maybe] your if statement"); break; }
}
console.log("process end");
```

Comment: So... can I put break by the comment outs?

Comment: That's a logic part, I think. For now, your code can't get out of the first while loop. If you are simply mistaken due to indent, putting 'break' at the outside of 'if'. it might work.(私もあれで伝わらないかもしれないのでつけておきます。そこはこのプログラムの仕様の話なので、なんともいえません。現状は、一つ目のwhileが無限ループになっています。単純にインデントの勘違いであれば、二つ目を一つ下げることで無限ループではなくなりますが...)

Comment: Let’s see... How can I put ‘break’ out of ‘if’?

Comment: Since your code doesn’t have a correct indent, I thought you might have confused and made a mistake, when you wrote it.

Comment: Like I said, that is a logic part. Why did you put the second break in that part?, and what do you mean by if statement ’(j+1) % 10 == 0’? You should know the purpose, right? I can’t say anything anymore, because I don’t know the details.

Comment: Hmm... can I ask you just one thing? You are saying like [if((j+1) == 10) break;] does not work in first iteration? I had thought “break” is a tool to get out of loop until a while ago...

Comment: Yes, but thing is, this program does not arrive to that part!, because obviously 'If statement' is something wrong.

Comment: I updated my answer(added snipet), you can confirm what I say.

Comment: Ah, I have to prepare limit, or it is going to be infinite loop, yes?

Comment: Again, if you prepare the limit variable, of course you'll no longer see an infinite loop, but I don't know whether it is properly behavior or not. It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help!, and I'm sorry to say a bit harsh comment.